# ping is not working

Tags: networking, server, ping

I have 3 VMs hadoop-masterTest, hadoop-slave1Test, hadoop-slave2Test, each one contains ubuntu server 18.04 .
this is the ping report :

**slave1 can ping to : master, slave1, slav2**

**slave2 can ping to : slave2, slave1**

**master can ping to :  master, slave2**

I don't know why I have this problem, event I have verified all the IP addresses and they are all correct

Comment: PS: I'm using virtualbox , and for the network adapter , I'm using bridged adapter for all vms

Comment: Can you add `ifconfig -a` and `route -n` from each system?

Comment: @WayneVosberg probably better to ask for `ip a` these days :)